# Computing the Value of a minimax tree

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trees, binary

I am asked to compute the value of a minimax tree, which each node labeled with its initial value. 
I am just unsure how to do it. 
I know that it is a minimax tree if:

1. the root is a min node, the value of the tree is equal to the minimum of

   - The integer stored in the root
   - The value of the left subtree, but only if it is nonempty
   - The value of the right subtree, but only if it is nonempty

     2. If the root is a max node, the value of the tree is equal to the maximum of the above three values. 
        [image]

I was hoping someone can guide me in the right direction and help me understand this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’ll get you started. Start at the bottom: the leaves have empty subtrees, so the value of each leaf is simply the integer stored in it. Now go up a level and work on the four max nodes just above the leaves. each of them is the root of a small tree with $3$ nodes. For the first one, for instance, we have this tree:

```
               0  
              / \  
             1  23
```

We’re dealing with a tree whose root is a max node, so the value of the tree is the maximum of $0$ (the integer stored in the root), $1$ (the value of the left subtree), and $23$ (the value of the right subtree). That maximum is $23$, so the value of this little subtree is $23$. Proceeding across, we find that the four subtrees whose roots are the max nodes at depth $2$ have values $23$, $99$, $98$, and $21$.

Now look at the left min node at depth $1$. The integer stored in it is $100$. We just calculated the value of its left subtree: that’s $23$. And the value of its right subtree is $99$. The minimum of these three numbers is $23$, so the value of the left subtree of the big tree is $23$.

Can you finish now?

Comment: ok so because $100$ is a min node we take the value of the left subtree.
So then do we move into the right subtree?

Comment: @Csci319: Yes. Or you can work on both sides at once, moving up from the bottom one level at a time.

Comment: so would would the value be $23+99+98+21$?

Comment: @Csci319: No: the two max nodes on the right have values $98$ and $21$, so the min node above them has value $21$, and the max node at the root has value $\max\{0,23,21\}=23$.

Comment: thanks. this whole minimax tree is very confusing. Do you know of any good sites I can read about it. I have done some research but nothing great has come up

Comment: @Csci319: I don’t, I’m afraid. I did a bit of searching to see if I could find something to recommend, but most of what I found is either pitched at a higher level or aimed specifically at programmers, and the rest didn’t say much more than you already have here.

Comment: thanks buddy. so the answer is $23$?

Comment: @Csci319: You’re welcome. Yes, it is.